# Rails Development Logging - Clamping Request Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I am developing a Rails application where I pass certain image data through request (base64). I need to do it that way since I do some processing on the client side. The problem with this approach is that it spams my server log a lot.

Is there a nice way to clamp the parts of request that contain the long base64 strings somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `config.filter_parameters` in your `environment.rb` file to filter specific parameters from logging. Or use the nuclear option and set `config.log_level` to a lower value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this config option exists for a different intention, but you could use

```
config.filter_parameters += [:base64_data]
```

in your `config/application.rb` file.